# wso2 WSRegistryService .Net client

Tags: .net, wso2

hello I am trying to add a new proxy service to the ESB through the "AdminServiceWSDLs"?

the only thing that i have been able to do is:

```
using wso2.localhost;
...
WSRegistryService service = new WSRegistryService();
```

can you provide me a simple example of how to add a new Proxy service to the ESB? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a Proxy service you can do it easily through UI. please refer the following [link](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/user_guide.html#Proxy). If your requirement is to achieve it programatically you need to have a look at this [thread](http://wso2.org/forum/thread/10598). please note the source code location in the thread may have changed now.

Comment: [2] does not have solution, it just point out what I already know: that is possible to call WSRegistryService as a WebService by enabling the ESB to expose it. My question was if there is any example of how to do it by using the WebserviceRegistry...thanks anyway